# How to handle NULL when using String.StartsWith method

Tags: c#

How do I handle a null when using the String.StartsWith() in a complex `where` clause ?

```
var value = _context.Repo.Pages.Where(r => r.Sdate <= data.Pdate && (r.Edata == null || data.RData <= r.Edata)
&&  ......
&&  ...... several conditions
&&  ......
|| (data.SisPlan.StartsWith("T") && r.SisN == data.SisCal));
```

I've tried `data?.SisPlan.StartsWith("T")` but get the message:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to opperands of type 'bool?' and
> 'bool'

I'm trying to prevent doing a null check outside of the `where` clause.

Comment: `data != null && data.SisPlan.StartsWith("T") && r.SisN == data.SisCal`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way is to write:

```
|| ((data?.SisPlan?.StartsWith("T") ?? false) && r.SisN == data.SisCal));
```

We rely on the `??` operator to get the null case and in this case we return a false value. The `??` is called the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

Basically,

```
var a = data?.SisPlan?.StartsWith('T') ?? false;
```

is a syntaxic sugar for

```
bool a = false;
if (data != null && data.SisPlan != null && data.SisPlan.StartsWith('T'))
    a = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. I updated my code and debugger still throwing exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Models.Data.SisPlan.get returned null."...

Comment: Try `data?.SisPlan?.StartsWith`

Comment: I usually go for `!= true` rather than `?? false` which admittedly looks slightly odd, but doesn't require brackets